# Appropriate neighborhood size for SOM

Tags: cluster-analysis, som

I'm doing a program that can cluster numeric data using Kohonen Self-Organizing Maps and I'm trying to make it as generic as possible. So, **how do I know the appropriate initial size of the neighborhood in proportion to the number of items (number of output nodes) in the dataset?**

Suggestions would also be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refine the neighborhood function as you wish.

If you define a circle around each best matching unit (BMU) you can choose this radius to be proportional to the size of your grid in the low-dimensional space (likely 2d).  Then you can make the radius remain constant or shrink according to a certain criterion until your last iteration.

Another option is to make the neighborhood fixed, as in a certain amount of surrounding nodes to the BMU.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have it "as generic as possible", there is probably only one possibility: **random**. But I'd suggest to make it "less generic as possible" and then you can play with parameters ...

Comment: Is there any connection between the number of elements in a dataset and the neighborhood size of the algorithm? I have always assumed that if there are more elements in the dataset, the neighborhood size should be larger as well. But I don't know the optimal proportion of it. Then again, I am just assuming, which is why I asked a question here.

Comment: well AFAIK there shouldn't be such connection if you have well trained system on well-chosen dataset. But do yo have it both? ;)

Comment: I just made the neighborhood size larger when the dataset is also larger. It still works well though. I'm just finding ways to make it even better. :)

Thanks for the inputs though. It's much appreciated. ^^,